# How to select the top row of each group based on a specific ordering?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a table with the following data.

- Table name [Data].
- PrimaryID: The primary id of the table.
- ParentID: The table references itself; this is a FK constraint to PrimaryID.
- DateTime: The time that this was last updated.

  ```
  PrimaryID        ParentID          Date
      1            null      1/1/2013
      2               1      1/2/2013
      3               1      1/3/2013
      4            null      1/4/2013
      5               4      1/5/2013
      6            null      1/6/2013
  ```

I want to select results that look like this:

```
PrimaryID        ParentID
        3               1
        5               4
        6               6
```

For each "group" (defined as all the entries with the same ParentID and that parent), I want to select the row that is the most recent, and also replace a null ParentID (which usually indicates that this row is the parent) with the row's own PrimaryID.

I'm really lost on where to even begin generating a query like this.

I have an inner select that looks something like this:

```
(SELECT PrimaryID, ISNULL(ParentID, PrimaryID) as ParentID, Date FROM [Data])
```

This looks like it's the right direction to start, but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @ypercube, something like this should work:

```
SELECT t.PrimaryId, coalesce(t.ParentId,t.PrimaryId) as parent
FROM YourTable t 
JOIN (
   SELECT coalesce(ParentId, PrimaryId) as parent, Max(DateField) as dtMax
   FROM YourTable
   GROUP BY coalesce(ParentId, PrimaryId)
) t2 ON coalesce(t.ParentId,t.PrimaryId) = parent AND t.DateField = t2.dtMax
```

And here is the updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66e19/5).

Comment: This will not always give correct results: **[SQL-Fiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bb58/1)**

Comment: Can you please elaborate -- which record is incorrect in your fiddle?  I added the coalesce(t.ParentId,t.PrimaryId) 5 minutes ago (didn't see that in the question before answering).  Thanks.

Comment: The `6` has disappeared from the results.

Comment: I think your Fiddle is off -- your 4 has a higher date :-)

Comment: You are missing the point, dates matter for the groups (rows with same parentId). See this: [test-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57394/1)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question -- I thought "most recent" would use the Date field since it is the time the record was last updated.  I guess using the ID works if OP wants the newest record.  Maybe I'm still missing something.

Comment: A possible workaround using your idea: [test-3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57394/9)

Comment: I think I finally understand.  NULL records (top level) group with their children -- this line helped me understand: (defined as all the entries with the same ParentID and that parent) -- editing my answer to include coalesce(ParentId, PrimaryId) in the join -- thanks @ypercube!

Comment: I wound up basing what I'm using off this answer. I'm using ISNULL instead of COALESCE just because I'm more familiar with that, but it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select primaryid,
  coalesce(ParentID, PrimaryID) parentid
from
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by coalesce(ParentID, PrimaryID)
                      order by date desc) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/540bd/5)